# How to verify Http/2 via okhttp?

Tags: android, okhttp, http2

Okhttp defaults to h2 protocol if the domain supports it.
The aim is to somehow detect that if the domain is on h2 and okhttp defaulting to h2, how can a developer get the confirmation that all calls are being multiplexed and going on a single TCP connection? 
I tried using `CustomEventListener` as suggested by [Jesse Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40013/jesse-wilson)
Still, I am not able to get 100% confirmation. Tried to get the connection info

````
```@Override
public void connectionAcquired(Call call, Connection connection) {
    logWithTime("connectionAcquired: " + connection);
}
```
````

The connection object gives `Route` address, port, proxy, socketAddress clubbed with cipherSuit and protocol. While the protocol is h2 as shown by connection object, I want to know that the connections are actually multiplexed and going over a single connection. There is no info about connection ids or anything which confirms the same. Pls suggest.
 Sample log:
[7 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{http://api.hotstar.com:443 , proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=http://api.hotstar.com/106.51.146.149:443 … cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=h2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the connections identity hash code. If the connections are different they'll have different values.

```
public void connectionAcquired(Call call, Connection connection) {
  logWithTime("connectionAcquired: " + System.identityHashCode(connection));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jess. I think this info should be documented somewhere on Okhttp official document.

Comment: That's what this StackOverflow question is!